# OCL restrictions and derivations rules

Tags: uml, ocl

I'm working with this UML model

[image]

do you know how I could obtain the Film with adult content that only can be sale to Customer that have over 18?. I tried this expression:

```
context Film inv:
  self.adultContent->notEmpty () implies
  self.Customer.age >=18
```

Comment: I'm not good at OCL but would guess that it should be rather `self.adultContent implies`

Comment: Are you sure you have the associations modeled correctly? And are they intended to be bi-directional or uni-directional? Try taking a second swing at modeling the associations but this time give each association a meaningful name. If you have trouble coming up with a name for the association it may not be needed. Having the correct associations with meaningful names will then  make it much easier to write the OCL constraint.

Comment: For a good example of how to model class with associations, look at slide 5 in this presentation by Jordi Cabot: https://www.slideshare.net/jcabot/ocl-tutorial

Comment: self.Customer.age >=18 is short for self.Customer->collect(age) >=18 which is a Bag/Integer type error. You could use self.Customer->forAll(age >=18)

Comment: "I" does not exist in UML/OCL. You need to use some model object as the recipient of your query. "obtain" suggests that you require a Film as a result. Your invariant is a truth assertion. You probably need to use a query in a Section to return a filtered set of Films. Once you express your requirement clearly we (or you) may be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain `adultContent Film`s by invoking

```
Film.allInstances()->select(adultContent)
```

. `age >= 18` is irrelevant since `Film.adultContent` occludes it. Or you could validate that your model is consistent by an invariant much as you have written after correcting the typos as already commented:

```
self.adultContent implies self.Customer->forAll(age >=18)
```

.

Comment: this option is in Film context, isn't it?

self.adultContent implies self.Customer->forAll(age >=18).

Comment: Yes. It's exactly what you tried but with two syntax errors corrected. (If you use Eclipse Papyrus you should see yellow squiggles under your mistakes.)

Comment: While editing I stumbled over the first sentence which does seem to be two half-sentences mixed in one. Could you please fix that?

Comment: @Thomas. Whose first sentence?

Comment: Ah. I see where the issue was. If you had inserted code highlighting the right way, this would not have happened.